# How to send username data in android?

Tags: database, server

I am very new to coding and am trying to create an app in Android Studio. 
I would like for the app to add people via their username, and then have the request sent for approval by the username. The username will contain more information (info about the person) that cannot be accessed until the person is approved by the username. 
How would I code such a task, and would I be required to have a server that stores the usernames and information contained in the username, or is there a way to do it without a server? If a server is necessary, what is the cheapest way about creating a server that stores the database of usernames and information (any free alternatives?).

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I am not able to fully understand your question but if you want to implement some sort of login method then yes you will need a server and also a web services to handle your request.
There is a link to a guide showing how to do it.

[Android PHP MySQL Login Tutorial – Android Login App](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/android-php-mysql-login-tutorial-android-login-app-3/)

Also about free server you can use sites like **[000webhost.com](http://www.000webhost.com)**